# How to retrieve current user information from Firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

This below code will retrieve all the information from the collection but i want to retrieve only the current user information. How can i do that?

```
class Booking extends State<BookingDetails> {
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Appbar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('User1').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new Text('Loading...');
                  default:
                    return new ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data.documents
                          .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        return new CustomCard(
                          title: document['name'],
                          description: document['phno'],
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                }
              },
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to store multiple documents for a user and i want to retrieve and show only his documents from Firestore how to do that?

Comment: use the user's id to get the user's document `Firestore.instance.collection('User1').document('${firebaseUser.uid}').snapshots()`

Comment: How is your data organized under User1?  How can you tell if a document belongs the the current user?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: I have added a field userId in my database, where i store userId along with other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve information of the current user, then in that case you have to retrieve one document. Example if you have the following structure:

```
User1 (collection) --> userID (document)
```

Then you need to do the following:

```
 Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData()async*{
     FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     yield* Firestore.instance.collection('User1').where("userId", isEqualTo: user.uid).snapshots();
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: getData(),
```

Comment: I dont have userId same as my documentId, i have a field in my database called userId where i store userId along with other information

Comment: then use a where query to get the userid and get that specific document